# WooCommerce duplicate sub categories and product slugs

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, slug

I'm building a website that allows you to hire or buy a product. I've set up the following product categories in WooCommerce:

- Hire
- Buy

Is it possible to have the same sub-category slug under each parent category? E.g.

- Hire

  - Sub category
  - Sub category
- Buy

  - Sub category
  - Sub category

When I try this, WordPress throws up the error message:

> The slug “sub-category” is already in use by another term.

It's important to have duplicate sub-categories as the customer has the choice of buying or hiring a single item. I'd also need to do the same with the product slug E.g:

/buy/sub-category/product-name

/hire/sub-category/product-name

**Currently I can only have:**

/buy/sub-category/product-name

/hire/sub-category-2/product-name-2

Comment: did you manage to find a workaround? I'm also building a website on the same structure/idea and would love to hear how you went with the structure for this one, from both technical and SEO povs.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( The client changed direction, so this method went out of the window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have duplicate category slugs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/is-there-a-way-to-have-duplicate-category-slugs)

Answer (score 2):

Too bad no-ones answered you on this simple question. I guess you've allready figured it out, but for anyone else wondering the same:

A WooCommerce Slug is the true path to a certain category/product the database uses to find the correct category/product (just like on a computer: `usr:\\My_Computer\Desktop\` or `c:\\programfiles\desktop\`), and can often be seen as a permalink in your browsers URL field (i.e.: `http://yourshop.com/clothes/pants/`).

This means that categories and products can have the same names, as long as the slugs are not the same (NB: within that category!)
You can have:

`/BUY/sub-category/product-name` and `/HIRE/sub-category/product-name` but not:
`/BUY/sub-category/product-name` and `/BUY/sub-category/product-name`

If you do not like the browser showing this, you can change your permalink settings, so that it looks like something like this: `http://yourshop.com/?P=123` but bare in mind that search engines don't look as kindly on this.

Answer (score 0):

Slugs refer to the URL that will be generated to  get the data from wordpress database based on the criteria.
In case if you put the duplicate Slug it is possible that the system may mess up and get confused on the data to be fetched.

So  in your above case you can try naming it in different way eg.cat-subcat1, catsubcat-2 etc,